# How to create horizontal scrolling PDF view using PDFKit iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios11, pdfkit, pdfview

Couldn't create horizontal scrolling PDF view in ios 10.
Is this possible in iOS 11 ? Using PDFKit - PDFView ?

Comment: This Q is out of scope of SO. Report the attempts you have made so far and ask a specific Q, if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
//configure the pdfView or use it from an outlet in Storyboard
let pdfView = PDFView(frame: self.view.bounds)
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "pdfFile", withExtension: "pdf")
pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url!)
//the important setting
pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: nil)
//add to subview if you don't use an outlet
self.view.addSubview(pdfView)
```

Comment: HI! Adding displayDirection after setting document is not working! However i have tried to set pdfDocument just before addSubview and is working! I Hope you have tested the above code before pasting here!

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati yes i've tested before post to stackoverflow as usual.

Comment: Sorry for my old comment, but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myfile", ofType: "pdf") {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) {
                pdfView.autoScales = true
                pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
                pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
                pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: [UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey: 5])
                pdfView.document = pdfDocument    
            }
        }
```